# Eslint plugin import throws "import/no-unresolved" on specific modules inside a Lerna package

Tags: node.js, eslint, lerna

I'm using Lerna for the first time, and I want to create a monorepo of microservices, so inside a service I have axios, puppeter & joi installed, so eslint-plugin-import takes them as unresolved because they are not in the root **package.json**

I don't know how to change my current Eslint config, and I'm pretty sure that I don't need to create an Eslint config for every service inside **packages** folder, because I have seen repos with lerna that do not do that

I'm using Airbnb's rules

```
"eslint": "5.3.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "17.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "2.16.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "7.12.4",
```

And, this is my **.eslintrc**

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": [
      "error",
      {
        "argsIgnorePattern": "next"
      }
    ]
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "mocha": true,
    "node": true
  }
}
```

**~/api-gateway/packages/service-accountancy/lib/scrapper.js**
2:27  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'puppeteer'           import/no-unresolved
3:22  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'puppeteer/lib/Page'  import/no-unresolved

**~/api-gateway/packages/service-accountancy/src/api/api.js**
  2:21  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'joi'  import/no-unresolved

**~/api-gateway/packages/service-accountancy/src/repository/repository.js**
  2:23  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'axios'  import/no-unresolved

**~/api-gateway/packages/service-accountancy/src/schemas/portalRequest.js**
  1:21  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'joi'  import/no-unresolved

Comment: I added a setting **"import/core-modules"** in my eslint config to whitelist the packages exclusive inside the service folder, this helped me to pass the eslint check, but It's just an approach, it does not look like a solution, at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **eslint-plugin-import** package was actually doing its job, those packages were no downloaded at the time Eslint was running